# API Blogger - Display image on mobile

Tags: php, api, blogger

I've got a problem by using the Blogger API in PHP. When I publish an article with a picture on Blogger by using API, the picture appeared correctly on desktop version of my blog but no on mobile.

For example:

I send the following article on Blogger

```
<p><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/10/03/21/13/mushroom-3722395_960_720.jpg" /></p><p>Test</p>
```

On the index of my Blogger on Desktop, the pictures are correctly displayed:

[Index Blogger on Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eb7Ua.png)

I open the same page on mobile, and all pictures have disappeared:

[Index Blogger on Mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKd3l.png)

I noticed that URL generated by Blogger are differents on mobile and desktop.

By inspecting element, the URL on mobile is exactly the same that I've sent thanks to the API (ie: https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/10/03/21/13/mushroom-3722395_960_720.jpg).

On desktop, the URL is totally different:

https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/proxy/...

If I edit the post directly on Blogger and if I replace the original URL (https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/10/03/21/13/mushroom-3722395_960_720.jpg) by the URL generated (https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/proxy/...), the picture appeared correctly on mobile!

Have you got an explanation? How I can display pictures on mobile by using this API?

Comment: are you always going to use pixbay? If so just regex and replace what you want and always send the "correct" url.

Comment: I don't use always Pixabay pictures. I've tried with pictures from other sources. Unfortunately, images don't appear on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Your blog uses two templates now one for desktop and other for mobile. The mobile template is one of old default blogger mobile templates which allow showing images that hosted on blogger only. Images hosted on blogger can be easily resized by change some values in image URL, that cannot be done with images hosted away off blogger.

Now you have to change mobile template and aplly the desktop template to cover both desktop and mobile.
[image: change mobile template]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, the only solution is to make and use a responsive template. Just out of interest, why URLs are different between mobile and desktop?

Comment: I don't think so it is really happen. non blogger hosted images does not be converted to `googleusercontent.com` link. if you are sure about that please send me your blog url for a check.